# Adding event to the context menu in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, qplaintextedit

[image: context_menu_now]

This is my Context Menu after right click on **QPlainTextEdit**. I want to add function to load data from file in **Context Menu**. Can I? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1: [`QPlainTextEdit::contextMenuEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#contextMenuEvent)**

You should override the [`QPlainTextEdit::contextMenuEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#contextMenuEvent) as mentioned in the Qt documentation:

> ```
> void MyQPlainTextEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
> {
>     QMenu *menu = createStandardContextMenu();
>     menu->addAction(tr("My Menu Item"));
>     //...
>     menu->exec(event->globalPos());
>     delete menu;
> }
> ```

You can connect the [`QAction::triggered`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) signal to your method (slot) to load the data or you can use one of the [`QMenu::addAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-2) overloads, which allows you to specify a slot directly.

If you do not want to subclass `QPlainTextEdit` (to override `contextMenuEvent`), you can use [event filtering](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) in Qt.

Note that `contextMenuEvent()` is only called when [`contextMenuPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) is not set (or set to its default value [`Qt::DefaultContextMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum))

**Method 2: [`QWidget::customContextMenuRequested`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested)**

As an alternative, you can use Qt's signal and slot mechanism to create the context menu when requested by the user.

The [`contextMenuPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) property should be set to [`Qt::CustomContextMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum), in which case the [`QWidget::customContextMenuRequested`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal is invoked whenever a context menu is requested by the user. This signal should be connected to your own slot, which should create the context menu as shown in the code above (Method 1).

**Using `MyQPlainTextEdit` in Qt Designer**

To use your `MyQPlainTextEdit` in a `.ui` file, you should implement it as a promoted `QPlainTextEdit` and use it in your `.ui` file instead of a regular `QPlainTextEdit`. See the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) for more information.

To be able to use your class in the Qt Designer, you should not forget to implement a constructor accepting a parent `QWidget` as is done in [the `AnalogClock` example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-analogclock-example.html). Note that implementing such a constructor is always a good idea, because Qt typically [manages ownership through a child-parent relationship](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Answer (score 2):

Building on @m7913d answer.

The downside to the techniques is you must derive from the QPlainTextEdit class for a very minor extension.  My preferred method, especially when using designer based widgets, is to add an eventFilter, and filter out the mouse event that is a mousebutton press

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(...)
{
    ...
    ui->plainTextEdit->installEventFiler( this )
}

MyWidget::eventFilter( QObject * obj, QEvent * event )
{
    if ( ( obj == ui->plainTextEdit ) 
      && ( event->type() = QEvent::MouseButtonPress ) 
      && ( dynamic_cast< QMouseEvent * >( event )->buttons() & Qt::MouseButton::RightButton )
    {
        // create menu
        auto menu = ui->plainTextEdit->createStandardContextMenu();
        // modify menu
        menu->exec( mouseEvent->globalPos() );
        delete menu;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```