Open file from QFileDialog in native file explorer via right-click in PyQt5?
In Firefox, if I download a file, there is a folder icon "Show in Folder":

... which when clicked, opens the native OS file explorer in the Downloads directory, with the target download file selected:

I would like the same kind of functionality - except I want it in a PyQt5 application, when QFileDialog is opened, upon choosing an action in the right-click context menu activated when the target file is selected; e.g. with the PyQt5 example (below), I can get this Qt5 dialog:

... so, when I right-click on a target file (like test.txt in the image), I'd like a "Show in Folder" action added to the context menu, and when it is chosen, I'd like the native file explorer opened in the directory that contains the target file, and the target file selected - like what Firefox does.
How can I do that in PyQt5?
Example code:
# started from https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-file-dialog/
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file dialogs - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.openFileNameDialog()

        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Do not use the static functions. Create an instance of QFileDialog and reimplement its context-menu handling. Look at the source code to see how it's currently implemented (i.e. qfiledialog.cpp and qfiledialog.ui). Most things have object-names, so findChild can be used to get a reference to the list-view, the tree-view and the context-menu actions. You then just need to disconnect the customContextMenuRequested signals and re-connect to your own slot.

Qt doesn't provide a way to open the system file manager and select items, because there is no standard for doing that in all systems. You need to use OS capabilities, see this post.

For showing the file in the system file-manager, you should use something like show-in-file-manager.

As noted in the comments, there's no built-in Qt support for this. Opening and selecting a file in the system file-manager is quite tricky and there are no perfect cross-platform solutions. However, there is a Python show-in-file-manager package that does a reasonable job if you don't want to develop your own solution. It then remains to subclass QFileDialog and reimplement the context-menu handling. (NB: this means it will no longer be possble to use static functions like getOpenFileName, which use an internal Qt instance of QFileDialog - unless, of course, you choose to reimplement those functions as well).
Here's a basic demo (only tested on Linux):
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QFile, QFileDevice,
    )
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QListView, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QToolButton,
    QWidget, QFileDialog, QAction, QMenu, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout,
    QMessageBox,
    )
# from PyQt6.QtCore import (
#     QFile, QFileDevice,
#     )
# from PyQt6.QtGui import (
#     QAction, QFileSystemModel,
#     )
# from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
#     QApplication, QListView, QTreeView, QToolButton, QMessageBox,
#     QWidget, QFileDialog, QMenu, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout,
#     )

class FileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOptions(QFileDialog.Option.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self._list_view = self.findChild(QListView, 'listView')
        self._list_view.customContextMenuRequested.disconnect()
        self._list_view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            self.showContextMenu)
        self._tree_view = self.findChild(QTreeView, 'treeView')
        self._tree_view.customContextMenuRequested.disconnect()
        self._tree_view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            self.showContextMenu)
        self._rename_action = self.findChild(QAction, 'qt_rename_action')
        self._delete_action = self.findChild(QAction, 'qt_delete_action')
        self._hidden_action = self.findChild(QAction, 'qt_show_hidden_action')
        self._folder_action = self.findChild(QAction, 'qt_new_folder_action')
        self._folder_button = self.findChild(QToolButton, 'newFolderButton')
        self._show_in_action = QAction('Show In &Folder')
        self._show_in_action.triggered.connect(self.showInFolder)
        self._model = self.findChild(QFileSystemModel, 'qt_filesystem_model')

    def showContextMenu(self, position):
        if self.viewMode() == QFileDialog.ViewMode.Detail:
            view = self._tree_view
        else:
            view = self._list_view
        index = view.indexAt(position)
        index = index.sibling(index.row(), 0)
        if (proxy := self.proxyModel()) is not None:
            index = proxy.mapToSource(index)
        menu = QMenu(view)
        if index.isValid():
            menu.addAction(self._show_in_action)
            menu.addSeparator()
            permissions = QFileDevice.Permission(index.parent().data(
                QFileSystemModel.Roles.FilePermissions))
            enable = bool(not self._model.isReadOnly() and
                permissions & QFileDevice.Permission.WriteUser)
            self._rename_action.setEnabled(enable)
            menu.addAction(self._rename_action)
            self._delete_action.setEnabled(enable)
            menu.addAction(self._delete_action)
            menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(self._hidden_action)
        if self._folder_button.isVisible():
            self._folder_action.setEnabled(self._folder_button.isEnabled())
            menu.addAction(self._folder_action)
        menu.exec(view.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    def showInFolder(self):
        if files := self.selectedFiles():
            try:
                from showinfm import show_in_file_manager
            except ImportError:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Show In Folder', (
                    '<br>Please install <a href="https://pypi.org/'
                    'project/show-in-file-manager/">'
                    'show_in_file_manager</a>.<br>'
                    ))
            else:
                show_in_file_manager(files)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Open File')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.dialog = FileDialog(self)

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        self.dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFile)
        self.dialog.setNameFilter('Text Files (*.txt);;All Files(*)')
        self.dialog.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec()


Many thanks @ekhumoro - in the meantime I also managed to come to a solution that works for me, posted below, which uses the show-in-file-manager library you recommended. Thanks again!

Well, thanks to comments of @ekhumoro and @musicamante, I finally got to a working solution, with class and usage example - but boy, was that a doozy:

A good document to consult on context menus is https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20context%20menus even if it is for PyQt5; that helped me (along with C++ sources) to go through the PyQt5 conversion of an example I posted here: context menu in QFileDialog
Then I had to consult the C++ sources especially on how to retrieve "currently selected file"
Finally I used show_in_file_manager, however since I use MINGW64 Python3 on Windows 10, os.path.normpath etc all convert paths to forwards slashes (even if you manually supply a Windows path with backslashes) which breaks show_in_file_manager - thankfully, there is a workaround here: supply path as_uri(), and use allow_conversion=False in show_in_file_manager

So, here is how the example below looks like on my machine:

Here is the code:
# started from https://stackoverflow.com/q/43890097/79194084#79194084
import sys
import os
import platform
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath # python 3.4
from showinfm import show_in_file_manager, valid_file_manager, stock_file_manager # python3 -m pip install show-in-file-manager
from PyQt5.QtCore import * # QFile
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTreeView, QListView, QFileDialog, QAction, QMenu, QActionGroup, QPushButton, QLabel, QMainWindow, QDialog, QFileSystemModel

class CustomShowQFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    """
    * https://forum.qt.io/topic/158937: "QFileDialog is not really meant to
      be overriden. Create your own dialog if you want something special." -
      however, there is an example there
    * https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1827-QFileDialog-and-subclassing: "When
      you subclass QFileDialog, you are subclassing the Qt QFileDialog, not the
      native one. Calling static methods like getOpenFileName() will have no
      other effect than showing the native dialog because they are *static*,
      they will not operate on your instance.
      Therefore, you must use show() or exec() to show your instance of a
      filedialog. I recomend exec() - that way, when the dialog has been closed,
      functions like selectedFiles(), selectedFilter(), etc. will return the
      correct value."
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, caption="", directory="", filter=""):
        super(CustomShowQFileDialog,self).__init__(parent, caption, directory, filter)

        #print(f"{valid_file_manager()=} {stock_file_manager()=}") # both are 'explorer.exe' for MINGW64 Python

        # disable file multi-selection - ensure only a single item (file/dir)
        # selection is possible; see
        # https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18815-Select-multiple-files-from-QFileDialog
        self.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)

        # must have self.show() first, so .children() are instantiated,
        # and .findChild works; but without extern call to parent .show()
        # afterwards, this self.show() on its own does not show a dialog window!
        #self.show()
        # note: QWidget::show() can call QWidget::showFullScreen(), which calls
        # ensurePolished() and setVisible(True); it turns out, to have
        # .findChild work, it is enough to just run .setVisible(True) - note
        # that this also shows the dialog upon instantiation
        #self.ensurePolished()
        self.setVisible(True)

        # fetch the QTreeView/QListView in the QFileDialog
        self.myTree = self.findChild(QTreeView, "treeView") # when QFileDialog in Detail View
        self.myList = self.findChild(QListView, "listView") # when QFileDialog in List View

        # get the actions for the original QFileDialog context menu, so
        # we can reconstruct it;
        # qt_rename_action and qt_delete_action are setEnabled(False) by default,
        # and should be enabled as per file permissions of selection (see
        # QFileDialogPrivate::showContextMenu, qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp)
        # here we just enable them regardless - where app has permissions,
        # they will work:
        self.rename_act = self.findChild(QAction, "qt_rename_action")
        self.rename_act.setEnabled(True)
        self.delete_act = self.findChild(QAction, "qt_delete_action")
        self.delete_act.setEnabled(True)
        self.show_hidden_act = self.findChild(QAction, "qt_show_hidden_action")
        self.new_folder_act = self.findChild(QAction, "qt_new_folder_action")

        # Define our custom context menu action, and
        # connect this action to a slot/handler method
        self.show_in_folder_act = QAction( "Show in Folder", self )
        self.show_in_folder_act.triggered.connect(self.handle_show_in_folder_act)

        # set up context menu policy
        self.myTree.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
        self.myList.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
        self.myTree.customContextMenuRequested.disconnect() # OK
        self.myTree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generate_context_menu)
        self.myList.customContextMenuRequested.disconnect() # OK
        self.myList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generate_context_menu)

    def generate_context_menu(self, location): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/44666427
        print("generate_context_menu {}".format(self.sender().objectName())) # "treeView" or "listView"
        #
        # as in QFileDialogPrivate::showContextMenu;
        # note QFileDialogPrivate::model is QFileSystemModel*,
        # not accessible in Python - but FilePermissions are
        index = self.myList.currentIndex()
        index = index.sibling(index.row(), 0)
        #ro = (self.model) and (self.model.isReadOnly()) # cannot
        perms = index.parent().data(QFileSystemModel.FilePermissions) # no .toInt(), is int already
        print(f"    {perms=}")
        # renameAction->setEnabled(!ro && p & QFile::WriteUser);
        # deleteAction->setEnabled(!ro && p & QFile::WriteUser);
        self.rename_act.setEnabled(perms & QFile.WriteUser)
        self.delete_act.setEnabled(perms & QFile.WriteUser)
        #
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction(self.rename_act)
        menu.addAction(self.delete_act)
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(self.show_hidden_act)
        menu.addAction(self.new_folder_act)
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(self.show_in_folder_act)
        #menu.exec_(event.globalPos()) # https://stackoverflow.com/q/65371143 -> not applicable here
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(location)) # https://stackoverflow.com/q/43820152 -> works

    def handle_show_in_folder_act(self):
        # as in QFileDialogPrivate::renameCurrent();
        # self.myList.currentIndex() works for both Detail View and List View;
        # .column() can be > 0 only for Detail view (when right-clicked over
        # e.g. file size column)
        #print(f"{self.myList.currentIndex().row()=} {self.myList.currentIndex().column()=} ")
        index = self.myList.currentIndex()
        index = index.sibling(index.row(), 0)
        # as in QFileDialogPrivate::deleteCurrent();
        # note QFileDialogPrivate::mapToSource is private, and not in Python
        #index = self.mapToSource(index.sibling(index.row(), 0))
        #print(f"{index.isValid()=} {index=}")
        fileName = index.data(QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole) # no .toString(), is str already
        filePath = index.data(QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole) # no .toString(), is str already
        perms = index.parent().data(QFileSystemModel.FilePermissions) # no .toInt(), is int already
        print(f"{fileName=} {filePath=} {perms=}")
        # NOTE: in MINGW64 Python3, filePath='C:/test/test.txt' with forward
        # slashes - this ends up as folder='/test' in launch_file_explorer of
        # showinfm, causing `folder_pidl = shell.SHILCreateFromPath(folder, 0)[0]`
        # to end up being None, causing "TypeError: None is not a valid
        # ITEMIDLIST in this context" in the desktop.BindToObject call;
        # so probably we need to ensure proper Windows line separators before
        # calling show_in_file_manager
        if "win" in platform.system().lower(): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387222
          # python pathlib fails to convert these forward slashes to backslashes
          # fpath = Path(filePath) # WindowsPath('C:/test/test.txt')
          # pwPath = PureWindowsPath(fpath) # PureWindowsPath('C:/test/test.txt'); same with filePath as argument
          # apparently, os.path.normpath can do forward slash to backslash? not for me
          #filePath = os.path.normpath(filePath)
          # well then, have to go manual; unfortunately show_in_file_manager
          # calls normpath itself, so we're back at forward slashes, and not
          # even allow_conversion=False helps:
          #filePath = filePath.replace(r"/", "\\")
          # what worked finally for MINGW64 python3 is to:
          # pass filePath as URI, and use allow_conversion=False
          filePath = Path(filePath).as_uri()
          print(f"{filePath=}")
        show_in_file_manager(filePath, allow_conversion=False) # verbose=True, debug=True,



#class MainWidget(QWidget):
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QWidget(self)        # for MainWindow(QMainWindow)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget) # for MainWindow(QMainWindow)

        #creation of main layout
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton("Click for file dialog")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)
        mainLayout.addWidget( self.button )

        self.label = QLabel("[path]")
        mainLayout.addWidget( self.label )

        # creation of a widget inside
        #self.monWidget = CustomShowQFileDialog()
        #mainLayout.addWidget( self.monWidget )

        #self.setLayout( mainLayout ) # for MainWidget(QWidget)
        central_widget.setLayout( mainLayout ) # for MainWindow(QMainWindow)

    def on_button_click(self):
        print("on_button_click")
        """
        Note: the "tradidional" use with the static .getOpenFileName(...) is
        like this:

        options = QFileDialog.Options() # https://stackoverflow.com/q/63012420
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        load_file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open .txt File", filter="Text Files(*.txt)", options=options)
        if load_file_path: # user has made a choice
            print(f"{load_file_path=}")

        However, as per https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1827-QFileDialog-and-subclassing,
        we cannot use that idiom for a custom subclass; instead we must block
        with .exec(), which will return an int depending on OK/Cancel button
        pressed:
          0: Cancel (QDialog::Rejected),
          1: Open/file double-click) (QDialog::Accepted)
        ... and afterwards use .selectedFiles()
        """

        # instantiation alone raises dialog for now;
        self.myqfd = CustomShowQFileDialog(self, "Open .txt File", filter="Text Files(*.txt)")
        retint = self.myqfd.exec_() # exec blocks; however here returns int
        print(f"{retint=}")
        if retint == QDialog.Accepted:
          print(f"{self.myqfd.selectedFiles()}")
          firstfile = self.myqfd.selectedFiles()[0]
          self.label.setText(firstfile)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#window = MainWidget()
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
window.resize(180, 160)
sys.exit(app.exec_())


Please try to reduce your code to a more readable version, as it really has too many and extended comments that make it quite difficult to read, not to mention the fact that you "switch" a lot between quote-based comments, single line comments and end-of-command ones. If you want to provide context to what you're doing, add that in the answer, then remove duplicated lines that are unnecessary (such as duplicated super calls). Your code styling is also quite confusing (unnecessary spaces within some parentheses or around operators, inconsistent indentation or spacing).

Also note that show() and exec() are quite different. The more appropriate alternative to exec() is open(), as it ensures that the appropriate window modality related functions are actually called.

Thanks @musicamante, good to know about show() and exec(). Re: style - if I post a Q, rarely I get an answer when I need it, so I must proceed on my own; unfortunately, I am not super intelligent, so official docs are rarely sufficient, so I have to look up other sources; I am also cursed with bad luck, so whatever I try first rarely works; as a result everything takes me a lot of time, the above took me upward of 10 hours to develop (where I've slept like 4 hrs in the last 24 hrs), and I like to leave to leave traces of where I got some info, should I have to come back to it. Sorry 4 mess

Related: exec is blocking and returns status on accepted/rejected, show and open are not - How to get the result of QDialog::show()?: "If you want to get the result of show(), then go with Qt signals/slots:"

"if I post a Q, rarely I get an answer when I need it" If you're in a hurry for an answer, StackOverflow is not the place to ask: some questions get answers even years after being asked. And I doubt you're just unlucky or not smart, you probably just need more experience for each task you cannot solve yet. "Leaving traces" is perfectly fine, but remember that SO is not a personal notebook: answers are for everybody, and it's important to ensure that everybody can easily read and understand them. Take your time, writing good answers will also help your own coding experience and knowledge.
